# Android Studio emulation error

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, android-studio, android-emulator

I'm learning android and I am using Android Studio. The thing is that when I launch a simple project, it says error (actually a warning):
W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
This problems does not let me execute the code of mainactivity.java, commented and marked with *** at the end.
I have already tried every answer to this topic given on this forum and none worked.
Does anyone have any leads?

Full logcat:

```
01-25 19:55:25.709    2129-2129/nic.ayclass30 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-25 20:49:46.938    2129-2129/nic.ayclass30 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
01-25 20:53:11.471    2129-2129/nic.ayclass30 W/dalvikvm﹕ method Landroid/support/v7/internal/widget/ListViewCompat;.lookForSelectablePosition incorrectly overrides package-private method with same name in Landroid/widget/ListView;
01-25 20:53:11.481    2129-2129/nic.ayclass30 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 107K, 5% free 4183K/4400K, paused 1ms, total 1ms
01-25 20:53:11.511    2129-2129/nic.ayclass30 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 83K, 7% free 4493K/4792K, paused 13ms, total 19ms
01-25 20:53:11.511    2129-2129/nic.ayclass30 I/dalvikvm-heap﹕ Grow heap (frag case) to 8.791MB for 4510092-byte allocation
01-25 20:53:11.521    2129-2138/nic.ayclass30 D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 125K, 5% free 8771K/9200K, paused 2ms, total 2ms
01-25 20:53:11.591    2129-2129/nic.ayclass30 W/EGL_emulation﹕ eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package nic.ayclass30;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //RelativeLayout layout1 = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout1);   ***
    //Drawing pixel = new Drawing(this);                                      ***
    //layout1.addView(pixel);                                                 ***
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

/*    class Drawing extends View{                                   ***
                                                                    ***
    public Drawing(Context context) {                               ***
        super(context);                                             ***
    }                                                               ***
                                                                    ***
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas){                           ***
        int width = canvas.getWidth();                              ***
        int height = canvas.getHeight();                            ***
        Paint color = new Paint();                                  ***
        color.setARGB(255, 0, 255, 0);                              ***
        canvas.drawPoint(width/2 , height/2, color);                ***
        int x, y;                                                   ***
        for(x=width/4; x<=width/4*3; x++)                           ***
        for(y=height/4; x<=height/4*3; y++)                         ***
            canvas.drawPoint(x, y, color);                          ***
    }                                                               ***
                                                                    ***
}*/ //                                                              ***
}
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that warning is preventing your code from running?

Comment: Because it is a very simple and objective code that just draws a pixel on the screen, and it is a copy from a tutorial, and the only thing that Android Studio is informing me that is wrong is that message.
Apart that what draws the pixel is opengl-es and the warning tells me that an attribute from it is missing (or something).
This obviously might be wrong since I am a complete new-by but it is my best guess.

Comment: That error is a red herring, I think.